# BATCH program crashes after goto command

Tags: batch-file

This code is part of a chat program that I am currently working on.  The '**else**' part of my program is the one that doesn't work. The program quits instead of going to **:home**

```
:join
cls
if not exist "C:/Users/Public/room.cmd" (
echo No room has been found.
echo.
set /p choiceretry=Do you want to retry? y/n 
if "%choiceretry%"=="y" goto join
if "%choiceretry%"=="n" goto home
) else (
cls
"C:/Users/Public/room.cmd"
echo A room has been found. 
pause >nul
echo Joining
set roomjoined=1
echo %roomjoined%
goto home
)

:home
echo this finally works
pause
```

I have tried changing the code several times starting from **'echo Joining'**

Anyone know why cmd quits?...
:) :) :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you run `room.cmd`; you *must* use `call` to return from it:

```
call "C:/Users/Public/room.cmd"
```

Otherwise, execution will not return from `room.cmd` to the original batch file that ran it.

**Hint:** Consider to use `choice` instead of `set /P` for <kbd>Y</kbd>/<kbd>N</kbd> decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please don't left justify your code blocks.  It's much easier to read code that's properly indented.

Secondly, when retrieving values within a code block, you need delayed expansion.  See `setlocal /?` in a cmd prompt for more information.  **This is the reason for the unexpected behavior.**  Your variables retrieved within the same parenthetical code block in which they were set won't contain the values you expect unless you retrieve them with delayed expansion syntax.  As an alternative, you could use the `choice` command and `if errorlevel`, which would result in a bit nicer user experience I think.

Thirdly, when testing user input, you should use the `/i` switch in your `if` statements for case-insensitivity.  This isn't relevant if using `choice / if errorlevel` though.

Fourthly, Windows paths use backslashes, not forward slashes.

I'd fix it this way:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

:join
cls
if errorlevel 1 set /P "=Retrying... "<NUL
if not exist "C:\Users\Public\room.cmd" (
    echo No room has been found.
    echo.
    choice /c yn /n /m "Do you want to retry? [y/n] "
    if errorlevel 2 goto home
    goto join
) else (
    "C:\Users\Public\room.cmd"
    echo A room has been found. 
    pause >nul
    echo Joining
    set roomjoined=1
)

:home
echo this finally works
pause
```